# logo size seems to shrink in html and css

Tags: html, css, image, width

I have a list of images as shown in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/5/embedded/result/) in which I have aligned images in a straight line.

In the fiddle, the last logo (as shown in the screenshot below marked by a red circle) seems to resize and I am not sure what are the reasons behind that.

[image]

The CSS codes which I have used in order to align the images in a straight line are:

```
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.images img {
  width: auto;
  height: 2.5rem;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS codes so that the **last logo (emma marketing logo) should have the same size as other logos**. At this moment, the size of every image is set to **auto** and height to **2.5rem**

On inspect, the logo seems to resize as shown below marked by the red arrows.

[image]

Comment: The actual image file has a large transparent area surrounding the logo. Crop your image before you upload it.

Comment: @Turnip The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/6/embedded/result/) without the transparent part.

Comment: @user5447339 now the image has a large white area surrounding the logo. The image is displaying the same height as all of the others. It is just cropped differently.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The actual image is `810x456`

Comment: You need to either crop the image by removing unnecessary padding around the edges. Either set it as `background` and play a bit with the `background-position`.

Comment: @Turnip I have copied the image from [here](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=woZu4zpa&id=BD3EB4D4804A36D26630FAE51BF4E25D0A855B38&thid=OIP.woZu4zpahcHJjYnbGgMKZwHaEK&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fassets.pcmag.com%2fmedia%2fimages%2f426849-emma-logo.jpg%3fwidth%3d640&exph=456&expw=810&q=emma+marketing+logo&simid=608037255401964585&selectedIndex=0&ajaxhist=0).

Comment: @Turnip On inspect, it becomes `71x40` pixels with natural size as `810x456` pixels

Comment: I don't think you understand what we mean by "crop the image". Look at this "cropped" version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7bQ6.jpg . I have removed ("cropped") the space around the logo. This is what you need to do in an image editor.

Comment: @Turnip I got it now. It worked for me. I am wondering if you can answer it below so that I can accept it.

Comment: Kevin Huang has already answered you. But really you should probably delete this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to crop the last picture, as you can see there's a large transparent area around it.

[image: Image to show what I said]

Comment: Huang Without transparency, it looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/6/embedded/result/).

Comment: I don't mean to make it without transparency but **to crop** the picture just like the "Inc" picture